# How to get multiselect optgroup values based on each label on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, optgroup

I have a select option with multiple optgroups. 
I want to select multiple values from each group & get values based on the label(of optgroup) on submiting it.

**HTML** code is

> ```
> <table>
>  <tr>
>   <td>Select</td>
>   <td>
>    <select multiple="multiple" id="multiGrpSel" ">
>      <optgroup label="Indutry Types" id="types">
>         <option value="1">Private</option>
>         <option value="2">Public</option>
>         <option value="3">Govt</option>
>      </optgroup>
>      <optgroup label="Unit Category" id="unit"> 
>       <option value="1">Micro</option> 
>       <option value="2">Small</option> 
>       <option value="3">Medium</option> 
>      </optgroup>
>    </select>
>   </td>
>  </tr>
>  <tr><th align="center"> <input type="button" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit"> </th></tr> 
> </table>
> ```

And on **submit**

```
$("#submit").die('click').live('click',function() {

    $('#multiGrpSel').find("option:selected").each(function(){
        //optgroup label
        console.debug('label='+$(this).parent().attr("label"));
        //optgroup id
        console.debug('id='+$(this).parent().attr("id"));

        // values based on each group ??
        id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        console.debug('value='+$('#'+id).val());
    });


});
```

If two options from 1st & 2nd optgroups are selected, I am getting the **label** & **id** , but the value are getting as blank.

**Output:**

```
label=Unit Category
id=unit
value=
label=Unit Category
id=unit
value=
label=Industry Types
id=types
value=
label=Industry Types
id=types
value=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you already have access to the values of those selected options, but you are actually trying to get a value from the `optgroup` and not from the `option` since you used the `optgroup's #id` to determine its value, that's why you always get a blank result for the value.

See a working code below:

```js
$("#submit").click(function (){
  $('#multiGrpSel').find("option:selected").each(function(){
        //optgroup label
        var label = $(this).parent().attr("label");
        //optgroup id
        console.log('id='+$(this).parent().attr("id"));

        // values based on each group ??
        id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        
        
        // gets the value 
        console.log("label: "+label+" value: "+$(this).val())
        
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="multiGrpSel">
     <optgroup label="Industry Types" id="types">
        <option value="1">Private</option>
        <option value="2">Public</option>
        <option value="3">Govt</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Unit Category" id="unit"> 
      <option value="1">Micro</option> 
      <option value="2">Small</option> 
      <option value="3">Medium</option> 
     </optgroup>
   </select>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value (text value) is just the text content of this.

```
console.debug('value=' + $(this).text());
```

If you want the real value (corresponding numbers) use this:

```
console.debug('value=' + $(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#submit").click(function (){
  $('#multiGrpSel').find("option:selected").each(function(){
        //optgroup label
        var label = $(this).parent().attr("label");
        //optgroup id
        console.log('id='+$(this).parent().attr("id"));

        // values based on each group ??
        id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        
        
        // gets the value 
        console.log("label: "+label+" value: "+$(this).val())
        
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="multiGrpSel">
     <optgroup label="Indutry Types" id="types">
        <option value="1">Private</option>
        <option value="2">Public</option>
        <option value="3">Govt</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Unit Category" id="unit"> 
      <option value="1">Micro</option> 
      <option value="2">Small</option> 
      <option value="3">Medium</option> 
     </optgroup>
   </select>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```